# sudo mkdir permissions

Tags: permissions, pam, mkdir

I added the option `umask=007` at the end of `session optional pam_umask.so` in the `/etc/pam.d/common-session` file. It is working fine as intended for all users.

However, I can't figure out how to manipulate the `sudo mkdir` permissions. It is always 750. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

SUDO changes the user umask as described on the corresponding man page:

> man sudoers

Then search for the umask work by typing:

> /umask

You must change the umask_override setting on /etc/sudoers .

Comment: There is no umask setting in /etc/sudoers. In this case the sudo mkdir command uses default umask?? Then, where is the default permissions mentioned??

Comment: You must add it to /etc/sudoers . There is such setting but is not on the default file, did you check the man as I asked you ?

Comment: I have read it. I'm not sure about many things in there. Maybe I understand kind of, but this is about sudo and permissions, so I need more research to be sure what I'm doing. BTW, everyone is mentioning about the manual. yeah I know the manual.